# Node.js WS package: Why is the send() callback called after the console.log()?

Tags: node.js, ws

I have a simple server that looks like this:

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');


function startSocket() {

    let socket = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 80 });

    console.log('Websocket started...')

    socket.on('connection', function(connection) {
        console.log('[open] JS: Connection open')
        connection.send('You have open a connection',(error, number=5555)=>{console.log(number)})
        console.log('JS: Closing the connection...')

        socket.close()
    })

    socket.on('close', function(event) {
        console.log('JS: Connection closed')
    })

}
```

When I connect with my client, the output is this:

> Websocket started...
> [open] JS: Connection open
> JS: Closing the connection...
> 5555

(After I send a msg from the client)

> JS: Connection closed

And this is my simple client side written in Python:

```
import websockets
import asyncio


async def connectSocket():
    async with websockets.connect('ws://localhost:80/') as ws:
        ipt = input()
        await ws.send(ipt)
        msg = await ws.recv()
        print(msg)


asyncio.run(connectSocket())
```

1. Why isn't the `5555` of the callback being printed before the `JS: Closing the connection...`?
2. Even though I call `socket.close()` immediately after printing `JS: Closing the connection...`, my callback function in socket.on('close') doesn't seem to be called until I type anything (input) on my client and send it to the server. Why is this? Why does the server wait until it receives anything from the client?

Comment: A wild guess here is that `connection.send` is asynchronous

Comment: I thought so too, but if it were asynchronous wouldn't it necessarily return a promise?